# How can I do ReplacementStrings matching in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I've been parsing some event logs for user name and domain info with the following:

```
$dn = @{ Name="Domain"; Expression = { $_.ReplacementStrings[6] } };
Get-EventLog -LogName Security -Newest 10 | Select $dn
```

This will return output as such

```
NT Authority
domaintest
domaintest
domaintest
```

This is just sample code from a bigger script.

I've been trying to add in a Where clause to match against $domain so that I can call the script with optional arguments which would act as a user specified Where filter for $domain.

I've tried

```
| Where $domain -matches "string" |
| Where $domain -like "string" |
| Where $domain.Expression -match "string" |
```

And a myriad of others. Is it possible to do matching against `ReplacementStrings` like this? I assumed these would work since `$domain` is returning a string.
Thanks

Comment: what are the errors you're getting? try |Where domain -match "string"

Comment: I actually figured it out - I should have been doing a match as such: |Where Domain -like "string"| instead of |Where $dn -like "string"

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for properties in Where-Object is:

```
... | Where-Object { $_.Domain -match "string" }
```

And with PS 3.0 and above:

```
... | Where-Object Domain -match "string"
```

[MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849715(v=wps.620).aspx)